# Checkbuttons in list box tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter, listbox

```
from tkinter import *
root=Tk()
root.geometry('50x50')
scrol=Scrollbar(root)
scrol.pack(side=RIGHT,fill=Y)
x=Listbox(root,yscrollcommand=scrol.set)
z=[Checkbutton(x,text=i) for i in range(100)]
for i in z:
    x.insert(END,i)
    i.pack()
scrol.config(command=x.yview)
x.pack()
root.mainloop()
```

Hi Guys i have got a problem with the code above, unfortunately after running this code it returns only set of digits rather than set of checkbuttons. What i did wrong with this code

Answer (score 0):

You cannot insert checkboxes into a listbox. A listbox can only contain text.